# Join limit in mysql for tables having different column count

Tags: mysql, database-design, composite-primary-key

I am trying to join 20 table with almost 6 joining condition between each tables. Each table has differenct coulmn count approx 280. each table has four composite primary key.Common for all 20 tables.
While executing query not able to get the column form all the table.

it seems there is some joining limit or may be final table is having some column count limit .

Please suggest some solution to combine there table and get the desired result.

Hoping for suggestions.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: If you have over 20 tables with over 280 columns per table, I suggest your database schema needs to become normalized.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. But I can't normalize all tables as i need column data from all tables to get the process info.

Comment: It seems that you do not understand normalization.

Comment: Normalization means... say I have a table with columns like 'name, email address 1, email address 2'. Instead, I should turn that into a column with just 'name, email address' and insert two rows. That way getting every email address requires only one column.

Comment: What are the relationships between the tables? If they are all 1-1, perhaps you want a `UNION` and not joins.

Comment: i can't use use "union " as table has different column count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such type of clause or rule "some joining limit or may be final table is having some column count limit" .
check your query properly some condition surely return false rows i.e condition not matched.
TRy to normalized ur table as it is very un-usual to make  Entity having 300 Attributes.

Comment: Most SQL distributions have a limit on how many columns a select can return at once.

Comment: max column as i tested in mysql is 4096.